# android activity not pausing

Tags: android, android-intent

I have two android activities(lets call them A1 and A2). The purpose of the first one ist to display several linear layout items. Also it features a button to add new items. When clicking on the add button using the following intent:

```
//...
Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreateActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
//...
```

the application should switch to A2 **pausing** the first one. When accessing a type on A2 I switch back to A1 with this:

```
//...
Intent intent = new Intent(super.getContext(), HomeActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
intent.putExtra("type", this._type);
super.getContext().startActivity(intent);
//...
```

intent, adding a new item to the layout which works. 
Now I've got the `onCreate, onResume, onPause` methods which are called every time I switch from A2 to A1. Is that the normal android behaviour?

As far as I understood the activity lifecycle the flags `NEW_TASK`, and `CLEAR_TASK` open up a new process pausing the Activity they're called in.

I've read several different documentations about switching Activities in android but didn't really get the point of how to explicitely tell an Activity to just pause and not call onCreate etc. again.

Comment: Why do u use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK ?

Comment: the purpose of these was to explicitly tell android to create a new task pausing A1. The second one should kill the task and return to A1 triggering onResume.

Comment: than u can just remove lines with intent flags, and from A2 activity call this.finish() when it'll finish their tasks

Comment: I already thought about that, but I have to transfer data from A2 to A1. So I have to send another intent transporting this data. Or is there a way so transfer data using `finish()`

Comment: you can use onActivityResult()

Answer (score 1):

I think here your Activity A1 creates 2 times ,because u have one and create another one in A2 activity, so u can just start activity A2 without

```
(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
```

flag and than when you need to back to A1 call

```
A2.this.finish()
```

think this will help and A1 onPause will start calling

Comment: Can I transfer an extra using `finish()`

Comment: u should just start activity A2 and after when it'll finish his work just call
A2.this.finish() from point where it finished his work and A2 will pop from stack and A1 become to top again, and than You won't have need to create new A1 activity because u have another one in stack

Answer (score 1):

`OnPause()` is called when an activity is partially visible to the user but the user is not able to interact with it. In your case, when the next activity launches, the first activity calls `onStop()`. `onPause()` is only called when an alert box or a dialog bix is displayed in the screen. Try writing your code in `onStop()`.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I've got the onCreate, onResume, onPause methods which are called every time I switch from A2 to A1.

This is normal because you query to recreate the activity with `super.getContext().startActivity(intent);`

Just call [finish](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()) inside A2 to return to A1.

You can also put flag [Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) to the Intent. The A2 activity will not be destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

1. **FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK** --> this flag will start new activity So first remove this.
2. Second if you want to send some data then A2 to A1 then startActivity by following method rather than startActivity()

> startActivityForResult

And you will get a callback in

> onActivityResult()